# Google Android Codelab code snippets license

Tags: android, google-code, code-snippets

Let us say I create a recycler view for `MyFeedItem` using snippets from [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-diffutil-databinding#3)

I copy snippets from the mentioned codelab to create below file first

```
class SleepNightDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<SleepNight>() {

override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: SleepNight, newItem: SleepNight): Boolean {
          return oldItem.nightId == newItem.nightId
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: SleepNight, newItem: SleepNight): Boolean {
         return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

***and just replace `SleepNight` with `MyFeedItem` and `nightId` with `id`  to generate "my" software below***

```
class MyFeedItemDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MyFeedItem>() {

override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MyFeedItem, newItem: MyFeedItem): Boolean {
         return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MyFeedItem, newItem: MyFeedItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

For brevity, let us assume that this is the only file in the software produced and I am selling this software commercially.

- Am I under some copyright violations here? (given no license info is mentioned on the website)
- If yes, what is the remedy
- For the same scenario, let us say that the snippet is under MIT license and I have produced the same single file software that I am selling commercially and keeping it closed source. Are there any copyright violations, if yes, then what is the remedy and can I keep it closed source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I under some copyright violations here? (given no license info is mentioned on the website)

If there truly is no license given, then you have indeed violated the copyrights on the code because you need a license to make copies and/or changes.

However, the overview page for the cource *does* have a link to a page with licensing information (https://developer.android.com/license) and that page states

> Unless otherwise noted, the documentation on this site, including any code shown in it, is made available to you under the Apache 2.0 license

The Apache 2.0 license is a permissive license that allows you to keep your modified version closed source, but you must inform the recipients of the app that parts of it are under the Apache 2.0 license and give them a copy of the license.

Comment: Thanks, found [Terms](https://developers.google.com/terms/site-terms) at lower left corner of the [codelabs homepage](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/). The [Terms](https://developers.google.com/terms/site-terms) page contains the Apache 2.0 info at the footer. Also found chrome://credits as a good example on how to provide license info in some section of your software